# How to pass the date as URL parameter

Tags: java, web-services, titanium, sakai

I am using the titanium to create some app for a particular web application through a webservice.

Here I am passing the date as a URL parameter to call a particular webservice method in java.And the date format is as like below

**2015-02-04T05:10:58+05:30**

In java service method the expecting parameter type as Date.So how can i send the above format of date through URL Parameter.

Comment: can't you simply send the long value? Btw. i don't know titanium or sakai, but you might need to send a POST request to be able to send this kind of value

Answer (score 4):

You can encode the time string using the [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) javascript function.

```
encodeURIComponent("2015-02-04T05:10:58+05:30");
```

Results in..

```
2015-02-04T05%3A10%3A58%2B05%3A30
```