# Trying to pass a date as a path variable on postman however i get error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to query my database by passing a date param as path variable on postman using a get mapping, however i keep getting this error    "I am trying to query my database by passing a date param as path variable on postman using a get mapping, however I keep getting this error

> org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException:
>   Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type
>   'java.sql.Date'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to
>   convert from type [java.lang.String] to type
>   [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable
>   @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.sql.Date]
>   for value '2019-07-24 11:50:34.896+01'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No
>   converter found capable of converting from type [java.util.Date] to
>   type [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable
>   @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.sql.Date]]

I have tried using the `@DateTimeFormat` as suggested by various people on line but it still isn't working.

```
@GetMapping("/walletledger/{fromDate}/{toDate}/{currencycode}")
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('SUPERADMIN')")
public List < LedgerResponseDTO > fetchWalletLedgers(
    @PathVariable("fromDate") @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) Date fromDate,
    @PathVariable("toDate") @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) Date toDate
}
```

Implementation

```
@Override
public List < LedgerResponseDTO > fetchWalletLedgers(
        Date fromDate,
        Date toDate,
        CurrencyCode currencyCode,
        Pageable pageable) {
        List < LedgerResponseDTO > ledgerList = new ArrayList < > ();
        ledgerRepository.findByExecutionDateAndExecutionDateAndCurrencyCode(fromDate, toDate, currencyCode).forEach(ledger - > {
```

Comment: Please share how you are making a request from the postman and use Date from java.util.Date

Comment: Hope you are passing value in yyyy-MM-dd, e.g. "2000-10-31" format.

Comment: yes i am . A sample : "2019-07-24"

Comment: Below is my endpoint path url:   http://178.62.71.55:9091/v1/services/walletmanagement/walletledger/2019-07-24 /2019-07-24 /NGN

Comment: Try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28323895/how-to-pass-the-date-as-url-parameter

Comment: form the error messages i can see the value `2019-07-24 11:50:34.896+01` you are trying to parse

Comment: changed it to just this "2019-07-24 " and it is the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@GetMapping(value = "/date/{from}/{to}")
    public String DemoDate(@PathVariable(name = "from") @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) Date from,
            @PathVariable(name = "to") @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) Date to)
    {
        return from.toString() + " "+ to.toString();
    }
```

*URL to be called*

```
localhost:8888/date/2019-07-25/2019-07-26
```

**[DateTimeFormat.ISO](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.ISO.html)**

[image: Postman]

Comment: This is the same thing I am doing though, same error.

Comment: Make sure Date is imported from java.util.Date

Comment: it is: import java.util.Date;

Comment: I just found that @PathVariable for currency code is missing, it might be causing issue after changing to this