# How to pass date in angular 8 GET request

Tags: angular

I want to pass date in angular 8 $http Get request. Please suggest me that what is the correct way to pass date.

i want to do something like this

```js
public getCalendarData(Date): any {
        let myResponse = this.http.get(`${environment.BASE_URL}/getCalendarData` + '/' + new Date().toUTCString(), {
            headers: new HttpHeaders().set('SESSION-TOKEN', localStorage.getItem('jwt_token'))
        });
        console.log(myResponse);
        return myResponse;
    }
```

I have to integrate this API https://api/getCalendarData/20-10-2020 with angular but I don't know how to pass date in angular 8 $http Get request,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular HttpClient Get method with body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54164149/angular-httpclient-get-method-with-body)

Comment: The date could also be a query paremeter https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34475523/how-to-pass-url-arguments-query-string-to-a-http-request-on-angular

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass the date as URL parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28323895/how-to-pass-the-date-as-url-parameter)

Answer (score 1):

This is what your url would look like with your current implementation:

`<BASE>/getCalendarData/Thu, 22 Oct 2020 09:18:59 GMT`

Certainly not ideal as the url contains whitespace and a comma.

I would rather propose to pass a timestamp to your backend:

`const timestamp = Date.parse(new Date())`

Then your url would look like this:

`<BASE>/getCalendarData/1603358349000`

As @MoxxiManagarm mentioned, another option would be to send the date in a mandatory query parameter, this would then look like this:

`<BASE>/getCalendarData?timestamp=1603358349000`

I think this is nicer, because the path variable usage suggests that there is a concrete usage for each unique date - which there probably isn't.

Yet another option would be to send a POST request as it can contain a body, in which you could format the date in any way you want. This is obviously not REST conform, but might be a pragmatic solution for now.